# How to embed pdf file in html?

Tags: php, html, pdf, iframe, browser

I want to embed pdf files in my html ( either using the embed tag or the iframe tag ).

I've tried the following two. **All work well on firefox but not on chrome, chromium and android browsers**.

```html
<embed type="application/pdf" src="myfile.pdf"></embed>
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="myfile.pdf" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I've also tried reading the *pdf* file with *php* and then using an *iframe* to display it like this

```
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=".$_GET['pdf']);
@readfile($CONFIG['PDF']."/".$_GET['pdf']);
```

Again, this doesn't work on chrome / chromium and mobile browsers. It only works on desktop firefox.

I'm not sure if this is important information but I've also **Set the X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM mydomain.com"**

[Here](https://unipi.kongkika.gr/?action=projects&pk=algorithms) you will find an example of what the issue is.

Is there any other way that I can embed a pdf file on a web page?

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Do they simply not render in Chrome or are they not requested

Comment: I do have an error message on my browser I hadn't noticed. It says "X-Frame-Options: “ALLOW-FROM mydomain.com". Based on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options this is Depricated. I changed it to "SAMEORIGIN" but the problem still exists.

Comment: It is _valid_, but you might want to scroll down a bit further to the “Browser compatibility” section on that page …

Comment: You are correct. I've changed it and there is no error message. PDF file still does NOT load on chrome / chromium etc.

Answer (score 9):

The Chrome browser on Android no longer supports PDF embeds. You can get this by using the Google Drive PDF viewer:

```
<embed src="https://drive.google.com/viewerng/
viewer?embedded=true&url=http://example.com/the.pdf" width="500" height="375">
```

You can also use Google PDF viewer for this purpose. You need to upload your PDF somewhere before and just use its URL:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview? url=http://example.com/mypdf.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:718px; height:700px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you. This actually worked! I tried the ' Google PDF viewer' so I didn't have to change a lot of stuff on the existing code.  I also found a codepen that made things even simpler in my mind. https://codepen.io/Ranjithkumar10/pen/PGogxW

Comment: Will this still work if the PDF requires authentication to access?

Comment: @Edward I don't know that, haven't applied it on authenticated PDF.